# Magento 2 Luma Theme inherence error 2.2.1 CE

Tags: theme, magento2.2, luma-theme, parent-child-theme, inheritance

I have a problem when I add a new theme in my new Magento 2.2.1 CE from scratch, and I try to inherent Luma theme. I sow to many examples but nothing work for me. If I put as parent blank work well but not for Luma.
I created inside

```
app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/
```

my files
registrations.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_code]',
    __DIR__
);
```

and theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Mbs Tutorial Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>   
</theme>
```

On the database my theme parent_id is Luma (id = 2), and I added to the store view design without problems, but they don't inherent Luma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good. Add new css file to your theme (you can copy from parent), flush cache and run static content deploy

Comment: I added new css and it works correctly, but I still can not do inheritance to theme Luma.

Comment: dev mode, static content deploy and flush canche works, ty